# Value assigning in kernel with threadIdx

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I tried a method so that the data transfer from Host to Device will not be used. Normally, we assign values to the elements in the Host array using a loop and transfer it to the Device. This works fine for me on 1D and 2D arrays. The new method i tried is, to give the values to the array elements in the kernel. I succeeded for 1D arrays. But, for 2D array, the result is `0`. My device can support (512,512) threads per block. The output values are coming fine upto Length=22 but displays '0' for Length=23 `[22<sqrt(512)<23]`. As per `[22<sqrt(512)<23]`, i can see that only `22x22` threads are being used. Whats the problem?? Why is this happening?

The Code:

```
    const int Length=23;
```

> **Main Function:**

```
    int A[Length],B[Length],C[Length],D[Length],*Ad,*Bd;
    int size=Length*sizeof(int);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Ad,size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&Bd,size);
    dim3 dimGrid(1,1);
    dim3 dimBlock(Length,Length);
    FuncG<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(Ad,Bd);
    cudaMemcpy(C,Ad,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(D,Bd,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    for(int i=0;i<Length;i++){
        printf("%d  %d\n",C[i],D[i]);
    }
    return 0;
```

> **Kernel Function:**

```
__global__ void FuncG(int *Ad,int *Bd){
    int tx=threadIdx.x;
    int ty=threadIdx.y;
    Ad[tx]=tx;
    Bd[ty]=ty;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your device can only support 512 threads per block. The maximum *dimensions* of the first two thread block dimensions are 512. A 22x22 block (484 threads) is a legal block size, but a 23x23 block (529 threads) is not.

You are getting 0 output because the kernel is never running. If you check for it, you will find the kernel launch is failing with an invalid execution configuration error. The canonical way to check for a launch failure of this kind is something like:

```
FuncG<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(Ad,Bd);
if (cudaPeekAtLastError() != cudaSuccess) {
    // handle error.....
}
```

Comment: I was going through the block size in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications). Is it (512,512,64) or (512,1,1)?

Comment: Each of the dimensions may be at most 512, 512, 64 respectively, but _also_ the product of all dimensions may not be larger than 512.

Comment: Does the same applicable to blockIdx??

Comment: Yes, there are limits on maximum grid dimensions as well, but these are not the same as block dimensions. There is also documentation, which I would encourage you to read. It contains the answers to everything you have asked in this question.

Comment: I think no. The documentation is a bit vague. Else i wouldn't have asked. Regarding grid dimensions, According to Wiki i posted, Does the dimension of the grid is (65535,1) or (65535,65535)??

Comment: 65535 x 65535 on compute 1.x, 65535 x 65535 x 65535 on compute 2.x, and  2^31-1 x 65535 x 65535  compute 3.x. Straight from Appendix F of the Programming Guide.